# Sequelize reload() wiping out all model data

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js, associations

I'm trying to reload a model in order to include association. This is my code:

```
const order = new Order({ total: 0 })

return order.save().then(savedOrder => {

    const orderItems = req.body.items.map(i => {
        return Eliquid.findByPk(i.eliquid).then(eliquid => {

         const item = Item.build({
           qty: i.qty,
           n: i.n,
         })

         item.setEliquid(eliquid)
         item.setOrder(savedOrder)

         return item
             .save().then(i => {
                 console.log('Saved, has id, has qty', i.id, i.qty)
                 return i.reload()
              })
              .then(i => {
                  console.log('Reloaded, qty is now NULL!', i.id, i.qty)
                  return i
              })
         })
    })
```

Why after reloading my instance it gets whiped out? Don't know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, `.reload()` (unlike `.save()`) doesn't deliver the item back to the client; instead, it synchronises the original item's properties with those on the server.

I'm not sure you actually need to reload in this case because client & server representations of the item will automatically be in sync immediately after `.save()`, but here's an example of how you would exploit javascript's "closure" to maintain access to the item, after `.reload()`.

```
const order = new Order({ 'total': 0 });
return order.save()
.then(savedOrder => {
    const orderItems = req.body.items.map(i => {
        return Eliquid.findByPk(i.eliquid)
        .then(eliquid => {
            const item = Item.build({ 'qty': i.qty, 'n': i.n });
            item.setEliquid(eliquid);
            item.setOrder(savedOrder);
            return item.save();
        })
        .then(ii => {
            console.log('Saved, has id, has qty', ii.id, ii.qty);
            return ii.reload()
            .then(() => { // .reload() does not repeat item back to client
                console.log('same ii as before', ii.id, ii.qty); // here, access ii through closure.
                return ii;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Notes:

- for clarity `ii` is used in the second .then() callback to avoid reusing the .map() callback's symbol `i`.
- the inner promise chain is flattened as far as possible. If you needed access to `eliquid` in the second inner `.then()`, you would need to revert to `return item.save().then()` and incur a futher level of nesting.
- in addition to exploiting closure, other approaches exit - see [the comprehensive answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/3478010).